# C - Array of pointers for strings - how to dynammically allocate memory

Tags: c

I am creating a program and in a learning phase of learning C. The given code is prototype for my code. What I want to do is dynammically increase length of array of pointers as I add new words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 20

int main(){
    char (*string)[0];
    char word[MAX_LENGTH + 1];

    string = malloc (sizeof(char));
    if(string == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Enter word: ");
        scanf("%20s", word);

        string = realloc (string, strlen(word) + sizeof(string));     
        if(string == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        strcpy(string[i], word);
        printf("%s\n", string[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d: %s\n", i + 1, string[i]);
    }
}
```

But what is happening is same word is stored in every string. Here is output

```
Enter word: hello
hello
Enter word: this
this
Enter word: is
is
Enter word: the
the
Enter word: output
output
1: output
2: output
3: output
4: output
5: output

---NOT OUTPUT BUT WHAT I WAS EXPECTING---

Enter word: hello
hello
Enter word: this
this
Enter word: is
is
Enter word: the
the
Enter word: output
output
1: hello
2: this
3: is
4: the
5: output
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I searched for hour on google, stackoverflow and reddit and didn't find anything I can relate too. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it. The compiler is not giving any error, output is blank in vs code.

Comment: `char (*string)[0];` is a pointer to zero-element array which is forbidden by C standard

Comment: `sizeof(string)` will return a size of *a pointer* which is constant (probably 8)

Comment: As the number of iterations is fixed (5) and there is cap on maximal lenght (`MAX_LENGTH`) then why not use `char words[5][MAX_LENGTH + 1]` ?

Comment: @tstanisl What I want is no fixed cap. I used 5 just to end program at a point instead of ending it by pressing enter or '\0'

Comment: OT: regaarding: `string = realloc (string, strlen(word) + sizeof(string));`  when calling `realloc()` always assign the result to a 'temp` pointer  Then check 'temp' pointer for failure and if not failed, the assign the 'temp' pointer to the 'string'  Otherwise, if the call to `realloc()` fails, then pointer to the allocated memory will be lost,, resulting in a memory leak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to do is dynamically increase length of array of pointers as I add new words.

You'll need to `realloc()` the array of pointers ("string") and `malloc()` for each word ("string[i]").

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 20

int main(){
    char **string = NULL;
    char word[MAX_LENGTH + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Enter word: ");
        scanf("%20s", word);

        string = realloc(string, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        if (string == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        string[i] = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
        if(string[i] == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        strcpy(string[i], word);
        printf("%s\n", string[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d: %s\n", i + 1, string[i]);
    }
}
```

*However,* if you know the number of words you intend to ask, it would be better to simplify and not dynamically allocate and resize the buffer. The code would be simpler and the performance if much better.

If performance is a consideration and the number of words is unknown, I would recommend reallocating every 512 words (assuming most common 64bit/4kB block size architecture), and preallocating much larger chunk of memory to split into words yourself, as keep calling `malloc()` for every word will be a major performance hit.

You should also consider different, less confusing variable names. `string` is not a great name for a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: I don't want to keep a cap. I started learning C and wanted to learn how to allocate memory for arrays of pointer. Used 5 to end the program instead of ending it with null character. It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is dynamically increase length of array of pointers as I add new words.

No, you don't. If you know in advance the number of words you intend to read, there is no sense in re-allocating the array of pointers again and again.

And while you may not be concerned with performance right now, you should bear in mind that dynamic memory allocation is quite an expensive operation.

Also, your choice of names is rather confusing: `string` suggests a single string, not multiple strings.

So, perhaps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 20
#define NUM_WORDS 5

int main(){
    char* words[NUM_WORDS];
    char word_scan_buffer[MAX_LENGTH + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORDS; i++){
        printf("Enter word: ");
        scanf("%20s", word_scan_buffer);

        words[i] = malloc(strlen(word_scan_buffer)+1);
        if (words[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation for the %d'th string failed\n", i+1);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        strcpy(string[i], word_scan_buffer);
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORDS; i++){
        printf("%d: %s\n", i + 1, words[i]);
    }
}
```

This also avoids using the "magic number" 5 repeatedly, switching to a defined constant; and fails a little more gracefully, by printing an error message instead of just exiting.

Finally, it's not even that useful to `malloc()` space for each word, when you could just `malloc((MAX_LENGTH+1)*NUM_WORDS)` once, setting the pointers in words to point to within that allocated buffer to begin with. See also this C FAQ question:

[How can I dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html)

which illustrates this option.

Comment: Even though I used 5 as a cap, I didn't wanted to. My notebook question was to dynammically allocate the  memory until user press enter and then sort the words by length and albhabet order.

Comment: regarding: `string[i] = malloc(strlen(word_scan_buffer)+1);`  since `string[]` was never declared/allocated in this answer, the code will fail

Comment: @user3629249: Yes, mis-copy-paste there.